# Moon landing conspiracies - you can kind of understand them given this report?

Tags: discussion

I was reading today that, in research published in The Astrophysical Journal,  molecular oxygen has been discovered in the Markarian 231 galaxy, 561 million light-years from Earth. A light-year, which measures distance in space, equals about 6 trillion miles.

So that's something 561 million x 6 trillion miles away.  Good luck getting Excel to calculate that!!

And yet we can't photograph the Apollo landing equipment 243,000 miles away.

This isn't a "moon landings were faked" troll, just an observation that you can see why people may think that way.

Thoughts?

Comment: Meta is not for this stuff. You should ask on the main site.

Comment: Please don't ask this on the main site. It is completely opinion based / open ended and is a terrible fit for space exploration stack exchange.

Comment: Hi @TimRichards, don't worry about the down votes here. You've asked in this in *meta* and here votes don't count towards your reputation. Instead, they are just a way for people to express themselves. I understand that you're not a "moon landings were faked" troll, but we do get them every once in a while, so sometimes people overreact.

Answer (score 2):

I could explain the reasoning, but as this is meta, I'll say what I think of such a question.

There could be a valid question as to why we can detect oxygen a very long ways away, while we can't see something on the Moon. This kind of question isn't really on topic on this site, but could be on astronomy.

Comment: I believe this has already been asked and answered on Astronomy.

Answer (score 2):

I don't use Excel, but LibreCalc very easily tells me your sum comes to around $3\frac{1}{3}$ sextillion miles.
[image: 561,000,000 x 6,000,000,000,000 = 3,366,000,000,000,000,000,000]

I would suggest such comments indicate those spreading such doubts either have a poor grasp of the scales of space, or are deliberately misrepresenting them.

It boils down to [the lander is small, the galaxy is far away](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MMiKyfd6hA0)

(please note, they're not photographing molecules of oxygen at that distance)